# Cannot load assets in dev mode on rails app : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I just started working on a new rails app that was developed by another developper and I must take on the projet.
I am experiencing difficulty at the setup level when simply trying to run the app locally in dev mode. 
The app doesnt manage to load the assets (css, js, images). I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` for every asset file :
[image]

I must add that the project is using the

```
gem 'asset_sync', '~> 1.0.0'
```

which is used to synchronises Assets between Rails and S3 but which, I think, should not play any role in dev mode.

Do you know why the assets are not loaded by the app in dev mode ?

Comment: Did you run rake assets:precompile command ?

Comment: Also can you mention the rails version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the screenshot I saw you are accessing [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) but your assets are being requested from [localhost:5000](http://localhost:5000). May be some server on port 5000 is needed to serve assets ? Can you check if [localhost:5000](http://localhost:5000) is accessible and is running some server that can serve your assets.